# Bash: Find which symbolic links exists to a specific file

Tags: bash, symlink

Given a file somewhere in the file system, can I find out which symbolic links exists that point to that file?

The purpose of this would be to determine if a file can be successfully deleted, or if deleting the file would leave behind a bunch of dead symbolic links.

If you do an "ls -l" in a directory that contains a file which is a symbolic link, the ls command will show you where the link goes. I'm looking for the reverse of that, which is getting a list of symbolic links around the file system which point to a specific file.

For example:

```
$ ls --optionToFindSymLinks? ./thefile.txt
/home/user/dir/file.txt -> ./thefile.txt
/home/otheruser/dir/file2.txt -> ./thefile.txt
2 symbolic links found
```

I realise that unmounted file systems might contain links that I won't be able to find, but this would not be a problem in my case.

Edit: Attempt at clarification

Comment: How is it unclear? I provide an example of the command functionality I'm looking for and the desired output. I just need someone to tell me what such a command might be. What is it about this question that you don't understand?

Comment: StackOverflow is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about basic command use, you might want to search for related questions at http://SuperUser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/. I've voted to close this question, as it's off-topic for this site. (If, however, you were to try to write a tool like this and needed some help with your code, this would definitely be the place to ask!)

Comment: Well, the question was related to Bash which is for scripting which is a kind of programming. It's not about how to use the "ls" command, this was just to illustrate the kind of functionality I was looking for. Right now there are 102000+ questions tagged with "Bash", tons and tons of them are how to make certain scripting functionality work, how to combine commands, how to extract information, how bash does things relative to the file system - etc. I don't see how my question stands out from all those other questions, but then again I'm not the moderator so do as you see fit.

Comment: Hm. Well, your "meta code" consisted of a fictional option to the `ls` command, which is of course not part of bash, but the SO help centre [describes a number of off-topic topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) a number of which might apply here. (I'm looking at #'s 4 and 6 in that list.) Many other bash questions have to do with variable or array manipulation, program structure, etc. Yours is about how the filesystem works, or is a recommendation for a tool. If you agree that it's not on-topic, I'd invite you to withdraw it and try one of the other sites I mentioned!

Comment: Using the "ls" command was simply a placeholder for some command X which I was looking for. I was illustrating desired behavior using the ls command along with a pseudo parameter. The parameter was named to avoid mistaking it for an actual parameter. The question was not how the filesystem works but how to find a specific file. Looking at goo.gl/k6Xvva there is a multitude of questions that work around the same premise - how do I do this or that in a bash script, using this and that command. I don't agree that the question is off topic.

Comment: So .. either you are fishing for an external tool ("command X"), or you are hoping that someone will write a program for you as an answer. Both of those are off-topic, for the reason I noted above. You could write a program, then ask here if you ran into difficulties, and *that* would be on-topic. StackOverflow is about programmers helping programmers with their code. It's not a tool reference or general helpdesk.

Comment: If you can call "asking the Stackoverflow community" for "fishing for a tool" then you're right, I'm fishing. Like everyone else? I'm not going to write any programs if bash or someone out there knows a way to get grep, find, which, ls or locate to find the information for me. And what's wrong with hoping someone will help write a small bash script? This thankfully happens all the time here on Stackoverflow. Please stop this crusade of pedantic commentary. Find another moderator to back up your views and please get off my back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reverse search. You have to do the work yourself. Get a list of all the symbolic links in your system and check which of them point to the file you are interested in.

Comment: ... whilst noting that they may be relative rather than absolute. Good luck!

Comment: Right, they may be relative... The best shot is to use a find to get all symbolic links and compare against the canonical representation of the real file at the end of the link (`readlink -f`), unless you are trying to find links to links, in that case you will have to cope with the several symbolic representations of the same file.

Comment: Thanks for these replies although they are not what I hoped for :-) I guess I was hoping that tools like the "locate" command might have something built into it that could output symlinks going to a specific file.